# kafka stream left join that has many to one mapping

Tags: java, lambda, apache-kafka

Previously, the left join worked as the value-joiner (**Please notice: joiner.apply(..)**) returned only one record as:

```
    KStream<String,Pair<String, Recipient>> joinedStream = aclInputStream
        .leftJoin(recipientTable,
                (recipientNotifyMsg,recipientDetail)->joiner.apply(recipientNotifyMsg,recipientDetail));
```

For a requirement change, this joiner.apply(..) returns a list of records. I getting hard time to do **many to one mapping** to change the output of joiner.apply(..) [which is a list] and push into the **joinedStream** [which expects single value].Was trying to do something like:

```
.leftJoin(recipientTable,
                (recipientNotifyMsg,recipientDetail)->{
                  List<Pair<String, Recipient>> list = joiner.apply(recipientNotifyMsg,recipientDetail);
                  list.forEach(pair -> return pair);
                });
```

May I get any help here?

Comment: It seems like a use case for `flatMapping`, but not much that I am aware of with the library in use.